# Conditional Sass based on item ID

Tags: sass

Not sure if this is possible, but what I'd like to do is have a conditional mixin with an additional condition based on the ID of an item.

So something like

HTML

```
<html id="eng">
   <body>
      <div id="content">
          <p>hello</p>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

SCSS (This doesn't work, but kind of gives you an idea of my problem)

```
@mixin font-select($weight) {
   @if $weight == 'light' 
   {
       html#chem{
          font-family: 'MinionPro-Medium';
       }
       html#eng{
           font-family: 'MyriadPro-LightCond';
       }
   }
   @else
   {
       html#chem{
          font-family: 'MinionPro-Regular';
       }
       html#eng{
           font-family: 'MyriadPro-Regular';
       }

   }
}

//MYRIAD PRO

@font-face {
    font-family: 'MyriadPro-LightCond';
    src: url('fonts/myriadpro-lightcond.eot');
    src: url('fonts/myriadpro-lightcond.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/myriadpro-lightcond.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/myriadpro-lightcond.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/myriadpro-lightcond.svg#myriadpro-lightcond') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'MyriadProLight';
    src: url('fonts/myriadpro-light.eot');
    src: url('fonts/myriadpro-light.eot#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/myriadpro-light.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/myriadpro-light.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/myriadpro-light.svg#MyriadProLight') format('svg');
     font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'MyriadPro-Regular';
    src: url('fonts/myriadpro-regular.eot');
    src: url('fonts/myriadpro-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/myriadpro-regular.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/myriadpro-regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/myriadpro-regular.svg#myriadpro-regular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MyriadPro-SemiBold';
    src: url('fonts/MyriadPro-Semibold.eot');
    src: url('fonts/MyriadPro-Semibold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/MyriadPro-Semibold.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/MyriadPro-Semibold.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/MyriadPro-Semibold.svg#MyriadPro-Semibold') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

// MINION PRO

@font-face {
    font-family: 'MinionPro-Medium';
    src: url('fonts/MinionPro-Medium.eot');
    src: url('fonts/MinionPro-Medium.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/MinionPro-Medium.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/MinionPro-Medium.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/MinionPro-Medium.svg#MinionPro-It') format('svg');
     font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}


@font-face {
    font-family: 'MinionPro-Regular';
    src: url('fonts/MinionPro-Regular.eot');
    src: url('fonts/MinionPro-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/MinionPro-Regular.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/MinionPro-Regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/MinionPro-Regular.svg#MinionPro-Regular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MinionPro-Semibold';
    src: url('fonts/MinionPro-Semibold.eot');
    src: url('fonts/MinionPro-Semibold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/MinionPro-Semibold.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/MinionPro-Semibold.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/MinionPro-Semibold.svg#MinionPro-Semibold') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

usage

```
#content{
    p {
       @include font-select('light');
    }
 }

 #other-content{
    h1 {
       @include font-select('bold');
    }
 }
```

Requirements:
All variations must use the same CSS file

The other option I was playing with was conditionally loading @font-family, but couldn't get that working neither.

Comment: What is the generated CSS and what is the desired CSS?

Comment: How many different places are you defining `font-family` that you need to write a custom mixin for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, from inside a mixin you can't see where it's called at.

I should say, the approach you're using is kinda weird. Try explaining your task instead of asking about a bad solution for that task we're unaware of (see [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)).

If i understood the task correctly, you want to leverage a combination of two techniques: the [extends](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#extend) and the [parent selector reference](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#referencing_parent_selectors_).

```
%font-light
  #chem &
    font-family: 'MinionPro-Medium'
  #eng &
    font-family: 'MyriadPro-LightCond'

%font-normal
  #chem &
    font-family: 'MinionPro-Regular'
  #eng &
    font-family: 'MyriadPro-Regular'


#content p
  @extend %font-light

#other-content h1
  @extend %font-normal
```

Results in:

```
#chem #content p {
  font-family: "MinionPro-Medium"; }
#eng #content p {
  font-family: "MyriadPro-LightCond"; }

#chem #other-content h1 {
  font-family: "MinionPro-Regular"; }
#eng #other-content h1 {
  font-family: "MyriadPro-Regular"; }
```

(I've trunkated the resulting CSS for the sake of clarity. In reality it will be kinda redundant. Seems SASS is trying to compensate that it's not telepathic and can't predict what you actually want. You can see the full resulting CSS [here](http://sassmeister.com/gist/5458986).)

Comment: I didn't know that you could use "&" after the selector. That did the trick. Thanks!